MySQLWorkbench on Mac: Authentication plugin cannot be loaded
When using MySQL Workbench to connect to any of my DBs, I got the error

Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 with user root

Authentication plugin '' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/.so, 0x0002): tried: '/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/.so' (no such file)

Here are the versions:

OS: Mac Sonoma 14.6.1;
MySQL Sever: version 5.7.44
MySQLWorkbench: version 8.0.40
MySQL Server and MySQLWorkbench are installed via Homebrew.

I have the setting in my.cnf.default: plugin_dir = /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/lib/plugin
The following mysql commands gave the results:
mysql> show variables like 'plugin_dir';
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                   |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
| plugin_dir    | /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/lib/plugin/ |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select user, plugin from mysql.user where user='root';
+------+-----------------------+
| user | plugin                |
+------+-----------------------+
| root | mysql_native_password |
+------+-----------------------+

I noticed this post Unable to connect to database with MySQL Workbench, but the solution for that does not apply to my case, since the solution suggested to use an older version 8.0.12 of MySQLWorkbench, but as I experienced, older versions (I tried 8.0.30) may not work with my MacOS Sonoma 14.6.1, i.e. MySQLWorkbench exit unexpectedly as reported here MySQLWorkbench quit unexpectedly on macOS Big Sur 11.1.
Can anyone please help? I encountered this problem after updating MySQLWorkbench from 8.0.30 to 8.0.40, but I have to update it since the older version has issues with MacOS Sonoma.

Problem solved after installing 8.0.36.
